# adding a pan gesture to a subview of a UIView called from a UIViewController

Tags: swift, user-interface, uipangesturerecognizer

I created a custom view with a subview where its frame origin x is set to the width of the parent view so that it looks like a tab sticking out of the view. (like a tab folder). The custom view is an IBOutlet in a view controller. My objective is to drag the tab to pull out the custom view like opening a panel. When I add the Pan gesture to the dragging tab, the subview, nothing happens. It works when I add it directly to the parent view. Any help would be awesome.

```
let pan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dragView(pan:)))
pan.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1
pan.delegate = self
notesView.dragView.addGestureRecognizer(pan)
```

neither the func nor the delegate methods are triggered.

Comment: You have set subview's origin to the width of the Parent view. Is the subview visible on the screen? If not, it won't recognise the gesture as the user interaction would not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
//MARK: - Don't forget to add UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, when you add delegate to gestureRecognizer
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       
        //MARK: set panGestureRecognizer
        let panGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(panGestureRecognizerTapped))
        panGestureRecognizer.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1
        
        //MARK: set panGestureRecognizer delegate
        panGestureRecognizer.delegate = self
        
        //MARK: Set panGestureRecognizer to view
        view.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer)
        
        //MARK: - Add user interaction to you custom view or view
        view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }
    
    //MARK: when tap is happened the below attribute will be executed
    @objc func panGestureRecognizerTapped() {
        print("Pan Gesture Recognizer Tapped")
    }
    
}

//The resource code is at the below link: 
https://github.com/ahmetbostanciklioglu/PanGestureRecognizer.git
```